# How to get access to request object from custom handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, mustache, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars with node.js and express and I have a custom registered helper for temperature display that I'd like to have access to a query parameter from the page URL.

The concept behind the helper is to handle Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion automatically based on whether `?tempFormat=F` or `tempFormat=C` is in the URL or not.  Here's the pseudo code for the custom helper I'd like to have:

```
hbs.registerHelper("formatTemp", function(temp) {
    if (query parameter says to use Fahrenheit) {
        temp = toFahrenheitStr(temp);
    }
    return temp;
});
```

So, I'd like my template to look like this:

```
{{#each temperatures}}
    <div class="row {{{stripes @index}}}"> 
        <div class="time">{{prettifyDate t}}</div>
        <div class="atticTemp">{{formatTemp atticTemp}}</div>
        <div class="outsideTemp">{{formatTemp outsideTemp}}</div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

---

I'm working around the issue now by pulling `request.query.tempFormat` and putting it in the data given to the template rendering:

```
app.get('/debug', function(request, response) {
    var tempData = {
        temperatures: data.temperatures,
        units: request.query.tempFormat || "C"
    };
    response.render('debug', tempData);
});
```

And, then passing that data in the template:

```
{{#each temperatures}}
    <div class="row {{{stripes @index}}}"> 
        <div class="time">{{prettifyDate t}}</div>
        <div class="atticTemp">{{formatTemp atticTemp ../units}}</div>
        <div class="outsideTemp">{{formatTemp outsideTemp ../units}}</div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

---

But, this seems messy because I have to pass the temperature units to every template render call and I have to then put them in every template where I want them used by a temperature display.  They're sitting there in the request object already.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to get access to the request object from a handlebars custom helper function?  That way, I could save code for every render and save code in each template and have the `tempFormat` query parameter just automatically apply to any use of `formatTemp` in my templates.

Does anyone know how to get access to the request object from a handlebars custom helper without using a global?

Comment: On a related note, does anyone know if there is a forum where handlebars issues are discussed where it might be more likely to find handlebars experts (since there has been no activity on this question)?

Comment: `location.pathname.indexOf('tempFormat=F')`

Comment: @raidendev - this isn't a browser, it's a server running node.js and it would have been in `location.search`, not `location.pathname` if it was a browser and I'm trying to avoid using globals so multiple requests don't have issues.

Answer (score 11):

First you need to assign your request object to the response local by registing a middleware anywhere before your route

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.local.req = req;
    next();
})
```

Then you could access the query object in you helper

```
<div class="atticTemp">{{formatTemp atticTemp ../req.query.tempFormat }}</div>
```

Comment: might be version specific, but I had to use: 
   { res.locals.req = req; }

Answer (score 2):

> Handlebars always invokes helpers with the current context as this, so you can invoke the block with this to evaluate the block in the current context.
>
> https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#basic-blocks

You can combine @Roland's answer with this feature to have your helper determine the correct format with a single parameter.

First add a middleware to inject the value from the request into the context for handlebars.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var tempUnits = this.req.query.tempFormat || 'C';
    this.locals.tempUnits = tempUnits;
    next();
})
```

Then in your middleware function, you can use `this.tempUnits` to access the value you injected.

```
hbs.registerHelper("formatTemp", function(temp) {
    var units = this.tempUnits;
    if (units == 'F') {
        temp = toFahrenheitStr(temp);
    }
    return temp;
});
```

Then you can have your single parameter helper that gets data from the request.

```
<div class="atticTemp">{{formatTemp atticTemp}}</div>
```

Note: You *can* add the whole request object, but it's cleaner to have the middleware inject the value you want.

Comment: this works only in top level hbs code. When you're in a different context, e.g. `#each` block, the context is switched and the `this` variable represents the current iterating item. In these situations `res.locals` isn't available in the helper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using express-handlebars package. You can register helpers on it's config object as below. Slightly differs from your way but you'll get the idea. To shorten the things, i've just added a second parameter in your helper function (:

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    helpers : {
        formatTemp: function(temp, unit) {
            console.log(unit);
            if (unit=="F") {
                return temp;
            } else {
                return 32 + (temp* 9 / 5);
            }
        }
    }
```

context data structure and the usage is the same.

tested.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help.  I already have a helper registered (it's shown in my question).  And, the units need to come from a cookie or query parameter, not from the template.

Comment: you just need to add a second parameter (unit) to the already registered helper function. source of the value is not a matter here. whereever you get the units (C|F) value from, all you have to do is passing this value to the view data context (as a second parameter to res.render function) and then use it in you helper call.

Comment: iow, you are a step away from solution. if you're changing helper call to `{{formatTemp outsideTemp ../units}}`, then your helper should receive 2 parameters... that's it.

Comment: just try this : `hbs.registerHelper("formatTemp", function(temp, unit) {
    if (unit === "F") {
        temp = toFahrenheitStr(temp);
    }
    return temp;
});`